# F# stream of armstrong numbers

Tags: f#

I am seeking help, mainly because I am very new to F# environment. I need to use F# stream to generate an infinite stream of Armstrong Numbers. Can any one help with this one. I have done some mambo jumbo but I have no clue where I'm going.

```
type 'a stream = | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream)
let rec take n (Cons(x, xsf)) =
  if n = 0 then []
           else x :: take (n-1) (xsf());;

//to test if two integers are equal
let test x y =
   match (x,y) with
   | (x,y) when x < y -> false
   | (x,y) when x > y -> false
   | _ -> true

//to check for armstrong number
let check n = 
    let mutable m = n
    let mutable r = 0
    let mutable s = 0
    while m <> 0 do
        r <- m%10
        s <- s+r*r*r
        m <- m/10
    if (test n s) then true else false

let rec armstrong n =
    Cons (n, fun () -> if check (n+1) then armstrong (n+1) else armstrong (n+2))

let pos = armstrong 0
take 5 pos
```

Comment: So where are you stuck on?  To me this code looks to have been written by two completely different people (the defn of `stream` is quite advanced, but the `test` function is a bit odd).

Comment: Does it need to be your `'a steam` or are you ok with `seq`? And please add a definition for *Armstrong Number* for those of us that don't want to go googling ;)

Comment: As Carsten pointed out, `seq` is the way:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd233209.aspx

Comment: Some quick googling has revealed that this is probably a homework question.  To @mambo I suggest you read this post on asking homework questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Thank you for for commenting. No I wrote but as I said, its all int the air, was brainstorming... example of armstrong number is 370 bc 3^3 + 7^3 + 0^3 is 370, but it is not limited to 3 digits number.. in general any number where the sum of the cube of each digits is equal to the number itself. I have to use F# streams, but clearly.. I don't know how. I really appreciate your help

Comment: If I wanted to do a stream of natural numbers it would be:          type 'a stream = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream)            let rec from (n : int) : int stream =
  Cons (n, fun () -> from (n + 1))
let naturals = from 0

Comment: If anyone wants to know where he is coming from - the lecture notes are here: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs3110/2012sp/recitations/rec27-streams/rec27.html

Answer (score 3):

To be honest your code seems a bit like a mess.

The most basic version I could think of is this:

```
let isArmstrong (a,b,c) =
    a*a*a + b*b*b + c*c*c = (a*100+b*10+c)

let armstrongs =
    seq {
        for a in [0..9] do
        for b in [0..9] do
        for c in [0..9] do
        if isArmstrong (a,b,c) then yield (a*100+b*10+c)
    }
```

of course assuming a **armstrong number** is a 3-digit number where the *sum of the cubes of the digits is the number itself*

this will yield you:

```
> Seq.toList armstrongs;;
val it : int list = [0; 1; 153; 370; 371; 407]
```

but it should be easy to add a wider range or remove the one-digit numbers (think about it).

### general case

the problem seems so interesting that I choose to implement the general case (see here) too:

```
let numbers =
    let rec create n =
        if n = 0 then [(0,[])] else
        [
            for x in [0..9] do
            for (_,xs) in create (n-1) do
            yield (n, x::xs)
        ]
    Seq.initInfinite create |> Seq.concat

let toNumber (ds : int list) =
    ds |> List.fold (fun s d -> s*10I + bigint d) 0I

let armstrong (m : int, ds : int list) =
    ds |> List.map (fun d -> bigint d ** m) |> List.sum

let leadingZero = 
    function
    | 0::_ -> true
    | _    -> false

let isArmstrong (m : int, ds : int list) =
    if leadingZero ds then false else
    let left = armstrong (m, ds)
    let right = toNumber ds
    left = right

let armstrongs =
    numbers
    |> Seq.filter isArmstrong
    |> Seq.map (snd >> toNumber)
```

but the numbers get really sparse quickly and using this will soon get you out-of-memory but the
first 20 are:

```
> Seq.take 20 armstrongs |> Seq.map string |> Seq.toList;;
val it : string list =
  ["0"; "1"; "2"; "3"; "4"; "5"; "6"; "7"; "8"; "9"; "153"; "370"; "371";
   "407"; "1634"; "8208"; "9474"; "54748"; "92727"; "93084"]
```

#### remark/disclaimer

this is the most basic version - you can get big speed/performance if you just enumerate all numbers and use basic math to get and exponentiate the digits ;) ... sure you can figure it out

Comment: Thank you Carsten, that's why I need to use F# stream bec it is a supposedly infinite list , I haven't learned seq yet, but thank you for explaining.